# How to set buy order for all items in dota 2 (immortals)

Tags: steam, dota-2

Today there was a boom on the Steam market as everyone was selling and buying Dota 2 compendium items, and I am trying to buy some immortals but am not able to do so as the rate is reflected every second and if I will see any item and tried to buy but couldn't as that item was sold one sec ago.

So, is there any feature in Steam by which I can set that I want to buy a item at a particular rate? I have seen this function while buying cards where you can set your rate, but is it possible to do the same for Dota 2 items?

I have read on Steam that they have updated their function for Steam market but I hope there will be any way by which I can buy some dota 2 immortal by setting the buy order instead of refreshing the page all the time and waiting for luck to buy.

I know if I will wait or am willing to pay more then I can buy but I know rate of these immortals will be very low soon so hope anyone will give me answer m looking for.

Comment: Do you mean something like auto-buy when the price is low?

Comment: not actually...as i wanted to buy zeus immo and bb's immo but from morning to till now, i couldn't able to buy so i thought there will be way where i can put my rate and as it will be in market in that rate..it will be automatically buy for me..so is there any way?

Comment: So ya... that would require a script/bot to auto-snipe the item when it is at a price you want.

Comment: that will be great..do you have any script/bot to do that as m new for that..please help me in this case..ty

Comment: Actually, Im pretty sure it is against the steam terms of service/subscriber agreement to bot purchases. [This Guy](http://www.pcgamesn.com/confessions-botter-how-one-man-amassed-and-lost-10000-worth-steam-market-items-armed-homemade-bot) botted $10,000 worth of items, and valve didnt like it so they took back all hit items and money. 

but, if you really want to, just [Google it.](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=market+script+steam)

Comment: wow..i wasn't aware of that..but i just want a short way to do auto buy in steam as i got tired by clicking on thousands of product but not able to buy :( i know in 3 days when rates will low, i sure will get chance to buy but was just thinking so..

Comment: Botting is generally against the rules for any game or digital service. Automatically buying an item from the Steam market is left up to a bot unless Valve puts the functionality in Steam itself.

Comment: @LucasLeblanc, believe me m trying from last so many hours but not able to buy any single item..thousands of people are buying items in cheap and then will sell in high cost..isn't it illegal or we true people have to pay extra?

Comment: @Leothelion It is likely due to either illegal botting activity or profiteers hiring minimal-cost labor to do it for them. Both of these things are against the TOS, but the issue is that the perpetrators usually live in another country which is diplomatically untouchable by an American company, like China. In these microtransaction markets, activity like this almost always shows up.

Answer (score 1):

Buy Orders are available on the Steam market: [(see the FAQ)](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6088-UDXM-7214%20%22(see%20the%20FAQ))

> **What is a buy order?**
>
> When buying a commodity items, you specify the price you want to pay, and when an item comes available at that price the purchase completes. If there isn't an item available immediately at that price, then that request to purchase stays active until an item listed at the right price comes along. This request to purchase is called a buy order. The buy order price is the maximum amount that will be spent; if an item comes along for a cheaper price, you'll only pay that lower price.

But these buy orders are *only* available for commodity items.

> **What is a commodity item?**
>
> A commodity is a kind of item where all the items are identical, and
> can be traded interchangeably. There aren't individual listings for
> commodity items on the market; instead you place an order to purchase,
> and an item is selected for you. This is very helpful when trying to
> buy items that are very frequently traded, and item listings can
> appear and disappear very quickly.

And since Dota 2 items tend to have different gems socketed (especially the immortals), they don't count as commodity items and buy orders are therefore not available for them. As far as I could see, buy order are not available for any dota 2 item, regardless if these items do have a gem socketed or not. I assume it is because of the ability to add sockets to normal items and thus changing them.

Comment: well thanx for info but this is not what i am looking for. I already mention there are some item you can buy like cards but how to buy dota2 item and you are saying you can't so sorry and thanx.

Comment: I would consider this the "official" answer. There is currently no support from Steam to do what you want and using the alternatives (bots) could result in negative consequences for you. I knew that this is probably not what you wanted to hear, but even a negative answer is an answer and maybe somebody else didn't know about this already.

Comment: thanx for answer but you know in google's first 3 record i can get these info so sorry i can't declare this as answer as may be it will lead to other user to wrong direction..sorry

Comment: Oh, that's totally ok. If it didn't help you, you don't mark it as answered ;)